# How is it possible that double buffering is enabled yet the back buffer doesn't exist?

Tags: opengl, c++, double-buffering

I am working on an existing OpenGL application and am currently trying to figure out why I am getting a black screen. So I am wondering how its possible that double buffering is enabled and the back buffer is being drawn to but the back buffer also doesn't exist?

This is what gets printed in Maya: Double buffering present, Back buffer doesn't exist, buffer being drawn to is back.

```
                glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, m_frameBuffer); // Read frame buffer is bound to our FBO object
            glCheckError();

            // call with a zero passed in breaks the existing binding of a framebuffer object to target.
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
            glCheckError();

            GLboolean   doubleBuffer;
            glad_glGetBooleanv(GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, &doubleBuffer);
            if (doubleBuffer) {
                MGlobal::displayInfo("double buffering present");
            }
            else {
                MGlobal::displayInfo("double buffering not  present");
            }


            if (glIsBuffer(GL_BACK)) {
                MGlobal::displayInfo("Back buffer does exist");
            }
            else {
                MGlobal::displayInfo("Back buffer doesnt exist");
            }  
             
            //since framebuffer object is unbound call to draw should draw to default
            //default holds back value for double buffered context 

            glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
            glCheckError();


            GLint drawBuffer;
            glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, &drawBuffer);

            if (drawBuffer == GL_BACK) {
                MGlobal::displayInfo("buffer bieng drawn to is back");
            }

            //check to see if anything is actually drawn to the back buffer


            // glBlitFramebuffer, glBlitNamedFramebuffer — copy a block of pixels from one framebuffer object to another
            glBlitFramebuffer(/* src */ 0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, /* dst */ 0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

Interesting to note as well if I don't add this flag `| PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER` to the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` then this update loop throws an error at `glDraw(GL_BACK)`.